# Color qubit lines using QCircuit

Tags: xy-pic, circuits, qcircuit

I'd like to *color* some qubit lines in quantum circuit diagrams drawn using QCircuit as exemplified in the following image:

[image]

Can this be done with Qcircuit? As a follow-up, is it possible to do some other modifications like making lines dashed, bold, etc?

The code producing the uncolored image is:

```
\Qcircuit @C=1em @R=1em {
   \lstick{|\psi\rangle} & \qw & \gate{R_x(\theta)} & \ctrl{1} & \meter \\
   \lstick{|0\rangle} & \qw {/} & \qw & \gate{U} & \qw & \rstick{|\phi\rangle}
}
```

Comment: Welcome! You have *way* better chances of getting a good and timely answer if you post the code that generated the above screen shot.

Comment: @marmot Thanks, I just added it. This specific circuit is not important though, my question concerns a general method to color the lines in any circuit. If there is one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading different comments on web I have finded a specific similar question in this link
https://github.com/CQuIC/qcircuit/wiki/FAQ.

At the end of the clarifications there is a specific question with an answer:

*How do I color parts of my circuit?*
[...] *LaTeX views the wires and gate outlines as a single object, so you cannot color them separately. The entire circuit or any text argument can be colored in the normal manner*.

Looking also this link that it is related with `Qcircuit` https://www.researchgate.net/publication/327592129_Tutorial_on_the_Quantikz_Package, you can see that all the wires are colored **only** with the black color.

This suggests that you can't color the wires with the colors of your choice. It will be interesting, lastly, to understand the source (with the full LaTeX MWE) of your first image where a thread is colored red.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I also couldn't find a solution. Maybe this could be added as a feature request on qcircuit's github. I'll keep this open a little longer to see if someone comes up with a solution. Anyway, I colored the first image by myself to explain what I wanted.

Comment: @PDRX I have also done other searches but the results are null. Unfortunately I have not found anything because all the results converge towards my answer. Your initiative on github could be a solution. I am always available. My greetings.

Answer (score 2):

I can, perhaps, partly answer this question. If, in your document's preamble, you add the line `\xyoption{color}`, then you can create customisations of the Qcircuit elements.

A simple example which will take you a step towards a solution is to add

`\newcommand{\qwred}[1][-1]{\ar @[red]@{-} [0,#1]}`

to your preamble. Then in a circuit you use `\qwred` instead of `\qw` and it will come out coloured red. The key part, which you can use to alter many of the Qcircuit elements (looking at the qcircuit.sty for what the commands should look like) is the addition of `@[red]` in the above `\newcommand`. I simple took the command from qcircuit.sty and added that, creating a new red line.

The complication, however, comes with the addition of gates. The command, as written in `qcircuit.sty` is:

`\newcommand{\gate}[1]{*+<.6em>{#1} \POS ="i","i"+UR;"i"+UL **\dir{-};"i"+DL **\dir{-};"i"+DR **\dir{-};"i"+UR **\dir{-},"i" \qw}`

If you include this in your preamble with the `\qw` command changed to `\qwred` (after you've created the `\qwred` command) like

`\newcommand{\gatered}[1]{*+<.6em>{#1} \POS ="i","i"+UR;"i"+UL **\dir{-};"i"+DL **\dir{-};"i"+DR **\dir{-};"i"+UR **\dir{-},"i" \qwred}`,

then this allows for something like what you've shown in your question.

This isn't elegant, and requires you to fiddle with each element of the circuit you want to create, but it's the only way I know.